# How to properly install wxPython?

Tags: python, windows, download, wxpython

So I was looking around at different things to do on Python, like code for flashing text or a timer, but when I copied them into my window, there were constant syntax errors. Now, maybe you're not meant to copy them straight in, but one error I got was 'no module named wx'. I learned that I could get that module by installing wxPython. Problem is, I've tried all 4 options and none of them have worked for me. Which one do I download and how do I set it up using Windows?

Thanks

Comment: It might be worth giving uis some more information. Which operating system which python version and which downloads did you try. ?

Comment: Please provide more details as to what have you tried and what is the exact problem in terms of coding that you are facing so that people can help you out.

Comment: my python is version 3.4.3, and i think that it's 32-bit. my OS is windows 7 and i've 32-bit. I've downloaded all four of the options: 32-bit Python 2.6; 64-bit Python 2.6; 32-bit Python 2.7 and 64-bit Python 2.7; they were under the title 'Windows Binaries', and I've also downloaded the demo for Windows.

Comment: I know it's late, but please add the details to your question. Use the *edit* button for this. As a description, *all 4 options and none of them have worked for me* is far too unspecific.

Answer (score 20):

It's on PyPI. As of wxPython 4, Python 3 is supported.

Unfortunately, PyPI has a package called `wx` that is stuck at version 3.0.3; be sure to install the package named `wxpython` instead.

```
pip install wxpython
```

**Please note** that `pip` will automatically build wxWidgets for you, but it will **not** install wxWidgets system dependencies such as GTK and OpenGLu. If the above command exits with an error, look above for a message like this:

```
checking for <something>... not found
checking for <something>... no
configure: error: <prereq> libraries not available
Error running configure
ERROR: failed building widgets
```

This should give you information about at least one of the packages your system is missing.

The "official" list of prerequisites from [the wxWidgets source](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/README.rst#prerequisites) is:

- dpkg-dev
- build-essential
- libjpeg-dev
- libtiff-dev
- libsdl1.2-dev
- libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev  # or 1.0 if available
- libnotify-dev
- freeglut3
- freeglut3-dev
- libsm-dev
- libgtk-3-dev
- libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev  # or libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev if available
- libxtst-dev

The actual package names provided by your package manager may not match these exactly, and to be honest, I don't really know the best way to query a package manager to determine what packages provide the libraries you need.

Comment: ```Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-mmON8T/wxpython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-2hOYji-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mmON8T/wxpython/```

Comment: @JirkaB. Okay, on Windows Subsystem for Linux, I'm getting a similar error, and there's additional information above. Do you get something like `configure: error: The development files for GTK+ were not found` if you look above that error line?

Comment: I haven't used Windows for many years... but now I see `No package 'gtk+-3.0' found` and `No package 'gtk+-3.0' found`

Comment: @JirkaB. I've edited my answer; you probably need to install quite a few packages before it works.

Answer (score 8):

3 steps to install wx-widgets and pygame in python IDLE

1. Install python 3xxx in your system opting (Add 3xxx to your path).
2. open python CLI to see whether python is working or not.
3. then open command prompt (CMD).

   - type PIP to see whether pip is installed or not.
4. enter command : pip install wheel
5. enter command : pip install pygame
6. To install wxpython 
   enter command : pip install -U wxPython

Thats all !!

Comment: Why [`-U`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/) for wxPython?

Answer (score 5):

As per [home page instruction](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip):

Make sure you have at least version 6.0.8 of pip and 12.0.5 for setuptools.

Install requirements for Linux as outlined in the readme.rst at:

```
    https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/README.rst
```

Install wxPython-Phoenix (Linux):

```
       sudo pip install --upgrade --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Install wxPython-Phoenix (Windows, use the appropriate script folder):

```
       C:\python27\scripts\pip.exe install --upgrade  --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Answer (score 4):

I installed wxPython as part of the PsychoPy experiment builder dependencies, and had considerable trouble getting it to install properly as well initially. But this was what worked for me at the end. I use Ubuntu 16.04, python 3.5, pip3 19.0.3

```
pip3 install -U     -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04     wxPython --user
```

Comment: Thank you, this one worked for me with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04 as well `pip3 install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-20.04 wxPython --user`

Answer (score 1):

If you use Conda then you may easily setup the environment with wx by one line:

```
$ conda create -n wxenv python=3 wxPython
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/user/.conda/envs/wxenv

  added / updated specs: 
    - python=3
    - wxpython


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    [...]
Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the versions of your wxPython download matches your installed python language library.

The current downloads [wxPython downloads](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) doesn't show any libraries built against python 3. I Believe the [python 3 porting project](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix) is still ongoing.

If you are not sure of what you are doing I would stick with the 32bit version on windows as there are some Python libraries (ie IIRC, MySQLdb) which don't work with 64 bit python.

So you would then need to [download python2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/) for windows x86  and "wxPython3.0-win32-py27 32-bit Python 2.7"

Comment: I downloaded Python 2.7.10, and the specified wxPython, but when the install wizard is almost finished, it gives me an error, saying: Unable to execute file: <file path>   CreateProcess failed; code 2. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Do not mix python 2/3 and 32/64 bit. Unless you know what you are doing, your Python setup will most likely not work as intended. Tip: Uninstall **everything** regarding python (especially 64 bit and Python 3.x.x). Then install Python 2.7.10. Report us what you get when you run the command ``python`` on the command line. Report what you get when entering ``C:\Python27\python`` on the command line. If you get a working python, the [wxPython 3.0.2 32 bit installer](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython3.0-win32-3.0.2.0-py27.exe) should work. If it doesn't, lets talk again.

Comment: I've tried again, but without editing the file path option, and now it's worked, thank you!

Comment: wxPython Phoenix does support Python 3, but as @rgammans noted, it is not complete. Phoenix only has the core libraries and a few of the others ported.

Answer (score 0):

To install wxPython GUI library correctly go to the following page (https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/), which contains snapshots builds of wxPython library (Phoenix version) depending on your os and version of Python you want to work.

Then when you downloaded the proper package for your system and python version, simply install it by using pip. In my case I've choosen that one (wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev2811+ecc4797-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl):

```
pip install wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev2811+ecc4797-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

To check that it has been installed sucessfully on the site-packages folder for your current python environment write:

```
pip freeze
```

It's all!

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of wxpython and the version of python you have in your machine.
For python 2.7 use wxPython3.0-win32-3.0.2.0-py27 package

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved in openSuse simply with

```
zypper in python-wxWidgets-3_0-devel
```

Trying `pip install` before, gave me a lot of trouble (missing traits, missing [wx/setup.h](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1067), https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1644, `error: aggregate ‘wxGLAttributes _NullGLAttributes’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

wxpython failed to be installed with pipenv. Pipenv is not able to find wxpython binary so it tries to build wxpython but fails.

```
CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include" pipenv install wxpython
```

On my macOS M1 pipenv failed to install wxPython. After a lot of searching I found a forum post which really helped me fix the problem.

Source/Credits: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=47953&p=203709

Answer (score 0):

Install current development version with:

pip install -U https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/archive/master.zip
(python < 3.9) Install current Beta version (2.0b1) with:

pip install psutil
pip install -U --pre robotframework-ride

Answer (score 0):

Note that I tried to install wxPython with 'pip install -U wxPython' as per instruction
with no avail. Too many errors to list here.

**I found a solution to the problem!!**

I'm working on a 64b machine and Windows 11 operating system using VSCode.

Here is the solution using PowerShell:

Version specs:

- pip 22.3.1
- virtualenv 20.15.1
- python 3.10.8

Create a new virtual environment in the directory where the program resides and
activate. There must be no modules installed.

- virtualenv venv
- venv/scripts/activate.bat

Install the following in sequence:

- pip install pygame
  (Not sure why pygame must be installed first, but this was
  recommended and it works)
- pip install -U wxPython

SUCCESS!!!

These are the modules installed:

- numpy      1.24.1
- Pillow     9.4.0
- pip        22.3.1
- pygame     2.1.2
- setuptools 65.4.0
- six        1.16.0
- wheel      0.37.1
- wxPython   4.2.0

VSCode still reports wx as a missing module even when you activate the virtual
environment within. Running the code from the PS command prompt within the virtual
environment is the only working solution.

PS. I am sure there are some conflicts when trying to install wxPython within an
environment where all the other modules are installed.