# Cannot install wxPython on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, wxpython, installation

The package I downloaded was wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7.dmg from https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython. I clicked on the file but got the following message at the end of the failed installation:

```
The Installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install.
```

I followed the steps by memoselyk on [Install wxPython in osx 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402303/install-wxpython-in-osx-10-11) but got the following message after calling the command in step 3 in the Terminal:

```
pkgbuild: error: output path "wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7.pkg" is a directory; specify a path to the package to be written.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you turn down your security settings before trying to install it?

Comment: After attempting to open the package file in the dmg (right-clicking open on dmg then package), I get the message 'the package is damaged and can't be opened. You should eject the disk image'

Answer (score 5):

This build will work on 10.11+: https://wxpython.org/snapshots/wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.3.0.b20160914-cocoa-py2.7.dmg

Comment: is this classic or phoenix?

Comment: It is classic. Phoenix is provided as wheel files and do not need an installer package.

Comment: There's no version 2.8.12.1 on that link. I need that version on my MacOS `wxPython not found.
You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with unicode support to run RIDE.
wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/`