# Couldn't install classic wxPython 2.8.12.1 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I use `Python 2.7.14` with `pyenv`

I try to run Ride IDE for Robotframework on macOS. I successfully install Ride with pip:

```
pip install robotframework-ride
```

But when I run `ride.py` I get error like this:

```
wxPython not found.
You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with unicode support to run RIDE.
wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/
```

I download wxPyhton from the [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/), but the installation failed.

[image: install wxPyhton failed]

The installer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40988207/1137814) works, but that's not the version that I'm looking for.

Comment: The 2.8.12.1 version is very, very old. If you must use RIDE, then you will probably need to downgrade your OS to use it.

Comment: OH damn. It's my workmate suggestion actually. Maybe I'll just skip it.

Comment: I don't know why RIDE hasn't updated their requirements to at least wxPython 3 if not 4. I have seen a LOT of people having issues with its requirements for software that is way out of date. You could always use a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem on some newer versions of macOS that complaint about security or file corruption of the package. Maybe in your case the extracted files were "quarantined", so it cannot complete the installation.

From the official [Wiki](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki) there are some restrictions on having to run python in 32-bit mode. Also the [BUILD.rest](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/BUILD.rest) file mentions some macOS options about 32-bit mode.

I have a fork from the original project, and some [releases](https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE/releases) that work with new wxPython versions. 
There is also the development branch `python3`, where I am trying to fix some bugs, mostly created by the changes in newest wxPython. You can install with:

```
sudo -H pip install -r https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE/raw/python3/requirements.txt
sudo -H pip install -U https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE/archive/python3.zip
```

(but be aware that it may have some bugs, including crashes)

We have a #ride channel on our Slack see [Robot Framework support](http://robotframework.org/#support) page on how to get the link.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the slack channel. I think I'll just skip RIDE and use atom with robot framework plugin instead.