# Installing wxGTK 3.0.20 on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, gtk, wxpython, pygtk

I am interested in installing wxPython 3.0.2.0 and wxWidgets with GTK on macOS High Sierra. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download that old version from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/). You may need to change your security settings in your Mac to allow you to install it though.

If that doesn't work, [Robin Dunn provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960855/cannot-install-wxpython-on-macos-sierra) this snapshot build that might work:

https://wxpython.org/snapshots/wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.3.0.b20160914-cocoa-py2.7.dmg

Please note that wxPython 3.0 is pretty old. You should consider installing wxPython 4, which you can do using pip:

```
pip install wxPython
```

Comment: what you're talking about is normal wxpython. i need wxpython which uses gtk.